# Python module reference with Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Let's considere the following function :

```
def format_send_event(self, message_identifier, payload=""):
    """
    Format a SendEvent.

    :param message_identifier: Message identifier (defined in the :py:module:`MyModule.constants` file).
    :type message_identifier: int
    :param payload: Payload of the message.
    :type payload: str
    """
    # Do something
```

When I compile it with sphinx-build, I have the following error :

```
...MyModule/handlers.py:docstring of MyModule.handlers.MyClass.format_send_event:3: ERROR: Unknown interpreted text role "py:module".
```

It looks like the sphinx-builder is unable to understand the tag `:py:module:`.

What is the tag used for referencing a module in Sphinx ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-py-mod), you should use `:py:mod:` to cross-reference.

Generally the shorter versions of tags seem to be used to cross-reference, and longer names to document.

Comment: ... snap I though `:module:` was equivalent to `:mod:`... Thank you.